# Creating a border of 1PX solid #89cFF0 is not working. It changes the shape of the menu. Why?

Tags: menu, border

I am trying to make a border of 1px solid #89cFF0 for my menu. You can see from the other "divs" that this is what I have done, and it has worked such as "hero" or "top video". What am I doing wrong? Many thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="videos.css" />
<title>Puppy Power</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="page">
<header></header>
        <div id="dog logo">
    </div>

<ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="indes.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Videos.html">Videos</a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li><a href="#">Vines</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pugs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Failing Dogs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Crazy Dogs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Funny Dogs</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>


        <li><a href="#">Photographs</a></li>    
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

<div id="hero"><h1><b>HERO</b></h1></div>


<div id="topvideo"><h1><b>TOP VIDEO</b></h1></div>

<div id="topphoto"><h1><b>TOP PHOTO</b></h1></div>

<div id="toparticles"><h1><b>TOP ARTICLE</b></h1></div>

<div id="content"><h1><b>CONTENT</b></h1></div>

<div id="footer"><h1><b>FOOTER</b></h1></div>

</body>
</html>

    #page {
    max-width: 850px;
    min-width: 840px;
    min-height: 1550px;
    max-height: 1600px;
} 

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}






ul #navigation, .sub {
    list-style-type: none;


}

ul#navigation li {
    border: 1px solid #89cFF0;
    width: 125px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul#navigation a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 125px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #89cFF0;
}

ul#navigation li:hover > a {
    background-color: #89cFF0;
}

ul #navigation li:hover .sub {
    display:;
}


#hero {
    width: 813px;
    height: 408px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;

}

#topvideo {
    width: 267px;
    height: 370px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;



}

#topphoto {
    width: 267px;
    height: 370px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;

}

#toparticles {
    width: 267px;
    height: 370px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

#content {
    width: 813px;
    height: 310px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer {

    width: 813px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-left: 1px solid #89cff0;
    border-right: 1px solid #89cff0;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several selectors that begin `ul#navigation`.  There should be a space between the `ul` and the `#navigation`.